# Subtracting one $_GET variable

Tags: php

My current code

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Returns: localhost/jamie/dashboard.php?p=1

However there will be instances where it will return: localhost/jamie/dashboard.php?p=1&sort=name

As well as: localhost/jamie/dashboard.php?view=list&p=1

How can I remove the p variable in my string? I wish to use a different value for $_GET['p'] that is linked on the same page

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?p=' . $cpage + 1; ?>
```

Returns: localhost/jamie/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` to get just the dashboard.php bit. Or probably better use 
[`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the parts of the url you need, eg something like this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts = parse_url($url);
$params = $_GET;
$params['p'] = $cpage + 1;
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $parts['path'] . '?' . http_build_query($params);
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way to do it actually. Fastest also.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting $cpage + 1 in parentheses: `<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?p=' . ($cpage + 1); ?>`.